# Why the SQL Server `replace` function creates undesired white spaces?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Given the `select` below:

```
select convert(varchar, convert(money, 15.2), 1)
```

The output result is:

```
------------------------------
15.20

(1 row(s) affected)
```

If I use a `replace` function:

```
select replace(convert(varchar, convert(money, 15.2), 1), '.', '|')
```

Then, the result is:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15|20

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Does anyone know why are there so many whitespaces after using the `replace` function?

How could I prevent (or fix) that behavior?

Comment: What does `LEN(replace(convert(varchar, convert(money, 15.2), 1), '.', '|'))` give you?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu 5, but that's not the question. I'm generating `rpt` files through a `select`, and my previous version generated 1.6GB of data, while the current one generates 2.4GB, because of those undesired white spaces.

Comment: You are using "Results to text", try change the mode to "Results to Grid"

Comment: @trungtin1710 the fact is that I need the "result to text" because of the whitespaces of other columns. In fact, I'm using "results to file", because I'm generating some rpt files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't add any white spaces.

The only difference is that the first one returns `VARCHAR(30)` the second `VARCHAR(8000)`.

The application you are using must treat these differently.

Comment: Why the second returns a `varchar(8000)`, and why it only has `256` characters instead of `8000`?

Comment: Btw, there is no application, I'm only generating a rpt file with the SQL Server Management Studio ("Results to file" option).

Comment: The return type of `REPLACE` is `varchar(8000)` when called on a non `MAX` `varchar`. Wrap the second one in a `CAST AS VARCHAR(30)` if you want it treated the same as the first. And SSMS is an application.

Comment: Could you please refer me any documentation about that? I couldn't find anything related to that both on SQL Server Help and on MSDN.

Comment: Btw, any idea why the `convert` function returns a `varchar(30)`?

Comment: 30 is the default length when not specified in that context. You can see the difference with `select 
   SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY ( convert(varchar, convert(money, 15.2), 1) , 'MaxLength' ),
   SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY (replace(convert(varchar, convert(money, 15.2), 1), '.', '|') , 'MaxLength' )`. Document for `REPLACE` is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx and doesn't say explicitly but mentions 8000.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help.